# React on Modal ViewController being dismissed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, delegates

I have three ViewControllers and one navigation controller. The Navigation Stack is:
NavigationController-push->VC1-push->VC2. VC1 can modally present VC3 in code. Its not connected via segues.
VC1 - "Your current projects"
VC2 - "Details of your project"
VC3 - "Create new project"

When user desires to create a new project, I put a VC3 using:

```
- (IBAction)newProjectButton:(id)sender {
    NewProjectViewController *newProject = [[NewProjectViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:newProject];
    [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I user presses "Cancel" button,  I use this code:

```
- (IBAction)cancelButton:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

When user presses "Done" button I want VC1 to make segue to VC2 and show new project's properties. I would like this segue to be invisible for user, so, he only sees this chain of events:
Presses the button "add" -> modal VC appears -> presses "Done" -> Modal VC disappears and VC3 is already shown.

What I am asking is how to tell VC1 that user pressed button "Done"? Is delegation possible here? How to implement it? Thank you.

Comment: Yep, delegation is the way to go. Check my answer for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a delegate protocol which allows the modal view controller to send notifications to its creator.

```
@protocol ModalViewControllerDelegate
@optional
- (void)modalViewControllerDidCancel:(ModalViewController *)vc;
- (BOOL)modalViewControllerShouldSave:(ModalViewController *)vc;
@end
```

Then, in `ModalViewController` you define a new property. The `weak` is important, because you don't want to have any retain cycles.

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <ModalViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

Before dismissing or saving, just check if the delegate has implemented the methods (via `-respondsToSelector:`) and send the appropriate callbacks. Don't forget setting the delegate property when creating your modal view controller.

Comment: Thanx! Am I correct, I need to implement your first code snippet in VC1?

Comment: No. The protocol should be implemented in a) its own file which you #import in `ModalViewController.h` or b) directly in `ModalViewController.h`. I recommend a) tho.

Comment: The reason why you do not want to declare the protocol in VC1 is because 1. the modal view controller has to have access to it and 2. it really is part of the modal view controller and could potentially be used elsewhere, without the need of VC1.

Comment: I misunderstood you. Then, why is it better to add it to own file rather than to ModalVC directly?

Comment: I doesn't really matter. I just like to keep things separated.

Comment: And am I correct that saving operation has to be performed by VC1? Or I can do it in VC3 and just use "did save"?

Comment: I would perform the save in the modal view controller. If the callback is 'should/did save', the name (in my opinion) implies that saving is done by that view controller itself. If you think of it, it would be kind of hard for other controllers to do the save without publicly exposing just about any property of the modal view controller.

Comment: Just one more tip: I would **not** call `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` in the cancel button action. Just send the 'did/should cancel' callback to the delegate, and let the delegate decide what the right thing to do is. Maybe later you decide that you don't want to present the thing modally, but just push it on the navigation stack. Or maybe even use it in different contexts in different places of the app. This way, the delegate would have control over how to present and how to dismiss the controller later on.

Comment: Still have a question - what to put in .m and what in .h files? Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58108/discussion-between-jenox-and-richard-topchiy).